# Using RabbitMQ with Rhino Service Bus

Tags: rabbitmq, rhino-servicebus

I've read Oren Eini's [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796225.aspx) on Rhino ESB and it mentions that it's possible to use ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ or others in place of MSMQ or Rhino Queues. But I'm having trouble finding any examples of using anything other than MSMQ or Rhino Queues. I'm researching RabbitMQ along with Rhino ESB for a project and I just can't find anything on the configuration I want. Can anybody provide some samples or links for me?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the Rhino ServiceBus code on [Github](https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-esb) and from what I can see there is no implementation for RabbitMQ. I can see an implementation for MSMQ (I use the MSMQ implementation).

However I would guess you could implement the RabbitMQ integration by looking at the MSMQ implementation. From a quick look at the [MSMQ implementation](https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-esb/tree/master/Rhino.ServiceBus/Msmq) it seems IMsmqTransport is the interface to implement. Once you have an implementation you can wire up the new implementations of the IMsmqTransport interface to get a working Rhino Servicebus using RabbitMQ.

If you are dead set on using RabbitMQ checkout [Mike Hadlow](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/)'s [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/)

After writing the answer I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362051/swapping-out-msmq-for-rabbitmq-in-nservicebus), which might prove useful if you want to implement your own RabbitMQ implementation.